# What should I do to make lifetimes in an iterator work when the compiler suggests using the move keyword?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a snippet of code which fails to compile:

```
struct A {
    x: [u32; 10],
}

impl A {
    fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = u32> + 'a {
        (0..10).map(|i| self.x[i])
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=64ad1231d94c6b261c8b680217a21beb))

The compiler says:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `self`, which is owned by the current function
 --> src/main.rs:7:21
  |
7 |         (0..10).map(|i| self.x[i])
  |                     ^^^ ---- `self` is borrowed here
  |                     |
  |                     may outlive borrowed value `self`
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `self` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
  |
7 |         (0..10).map(move |i| self.x[i])
  |                     ^^^^^^^^
```

What should I do to make this work? I need `self` later so I cannot move it as the compiler suggests.

**Edit**: I believed that `move` will create issues in using `self` later. For example, see the code:

```
struct A {
    x: [u32; 3],
}

impl A {
    fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item=u32> + 'a {
        (0..3).filter(move |&i| self.x[i] != 0).map(move |i| self.x[i])
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A { x : [0, 1, 2]};
    for el in a.iter() {
        println!("{}", el);
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=03769b0782088fed7e7df10dcc5458a7))

Here `&'a self` is being moved twice, so in effect, both the closures got ownership of `&'a self`. The code actually compiles but I did not expect it as once moved, a variable should not be usable anymore. The book ([relevant section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch13-01-closures.html#capturing-the-environment-with-closures)) also gives an example corroborating my understanding:

```
fn main() {
    let x = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let equal_to_x = move |z| z == x;
    println!("can't use x here: {:?}", x);
    let y = vec![1, 2, 3];
    assert!(equal_to_x(y));
}
```

This code does not compile. Why is it that my iterator code works with `move`?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. Based on the *code you have provided*, the existing answers solve your problem. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: @Shepmaster Sorry, I forgot include the bit that moving `self` into the closure, as suggested by the compiler, is not an option. I would need it to use it later after calling `iter()`. Please let me know if something else is incomplete.

Comment: As I already mentioned, please **provide code** that demonstrates the case where adding `move` to the closure will not work. We cannot magically create code that mimics your code that we have never seen.

Comment: @Shepmaster I made some edits to the question. The `move` keyword is actually working in my case but I am not able to make sense why.

Comment: Is it because I am just moving a reference, which gets copied instead of being moved?

Comment: Please rework your question it's unclear what you asking. Remove unnecessary code, and ask clearly what is the problem.

Comment: You have drastically changed your question, making existing answers irrelevant. It's no longer "how do I do X", but instead now "why does this code (which wasn't what was posted originally) compile". It's not fair to the people who took the time to answer your *original* question to change it so drastically. Please remove your new questions and ask a new question for what your new question is — [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266767/155423) / [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/281829)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the compiler is already telling you what to do:

```
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `self` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
  |
7 |         (0..10).map(move |i| self.x[i])
  |                     ^^^^^^^^
```

The `move` keyword gives ownership of any captured variable to the closure.

Here, you are capturing the `self` reference by move, not the object itself. You cannot consume the object by calling the `iter` method, because it doesn't accept your object by move, but by reference. You can [still use your object after calling `iter()`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=149438909dc5e1ce8883784b61d8b31d) on an instance.

Comment: Sorry, I almost assumed it was obvious... but I need `self` later. I have edited the question now.

Comment: @Shepmaster: OK, what would be the standard phrasing here? What I mean is that it gives additional contraints on the lifetime `'a` of `&'a self`.

Comment: It also doesn't give any extra constraints on `'a`. As you state, it transfers ownership of `self` (of type `&'a Self`) to the closure, as opposed to having the closure take a reference to `self` (of type `&&'a Self`). The latter does not live long enough as it goes out of scope at the end of the function.

Comment: OK, this clarifies things. For some reason I was thinking that closures were doing copies of captured variables for `Copy` types, so the reason why the example in the question was requiring `move` was actually becoming unclear to me. Apparently I'm not the only one: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/36569